# Cell culture contamination

Tags: cell-biology, cell-culture

[image]I've been culturing my cells over 2 weeks and just yesterday these things popped up in my flask , I'm not sure if they're contamination or not.uesterday they looked white and today I found one of them in black .Any ideas on what these things are?

Comment: we would need a picture to in any way ID what you are seeing.

Comment: What kind of cells are those? My immediate first reaction when I saw the image was mycoplasma. Bleach them immediately and clean the incubator thoroughly.